# Selenium не видит элемент

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Что не так в Selenium или xpath ?
Я использую `xpath` `//span[@id='responseDate']`, а проверка на наличие элемента приносит мне `false`, хотя в тоже время - я без проблем могу вытащить из него текст и нахожу его руками по xpath в панели разработчика chrome. И так же успешно вытаскиваю из него текст - если привязываюсь к любому другому элементу для проверки.

**1** фрагмент который не находился - но как то сам исправился после того как обновил метод неявного ожидания с помощью библиотеки `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`

```
<td class="footable-last-visible" style="display: table-cell;"><span id="responseDate">04.01.2020</span></td>
```

Так находит и вытаскивает текст

```
            if (ProverkaGotovnostiXPath("//input[@value='<<Назад']", Browser))
            {
                string text = PolucitTextXPath("//span[@id='responseDate']", Browser);
                .....
            }
```

А так не находит

```
            if (ProverkaGotovnostiXPath("//span[@id='responseDate']", Browser))
            {
                string text = PolucitTextXPath("//span[@id='responseDate']", Browser);
                .....
            }
```

**2** фрагмент до сих пор не находит

```
<p><strong>Номер там то: </strong>1244595735385395</p>
```

Использую такой xpath `//*[contains(text(), 'Номер')]/ancestor::p/text()`

```
    // Проверка на наличие элемента в DOM
    private bool ProverkaGotovnostiXPath(string xpath, IWebDriver Browser)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
            IWebElement elem = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(xpath)));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog("ProverkaGotovnostiXPath", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

В `ex.Message` получаю `Timed out after 10 seconds` - хотя элемент там есть

Ничем не перекрывается и не во фреймах

**UPD**

Проверил на всякий случай PageSource ручками и там тоже находятся элементы моими xpatch - а selenium не видит...

**UPD**
Пробую с Css selector - Тоже не ищет

Comment: Смешались в кучу люди, кони.. В методе, который `Проверка на наличие элемента в DOM` вы проверяете не наличие, а `ElementIsVisible`. `XPath`, а не `xpatch`. `что происходит ?` - это написано на вашем же скрине во внутреннем исключенни, надо просто дочитать проблему.

Comment: @tym32167 - да, видимость элемента - извините,он виден, но не находит.

Comment: ну то есть у вас есть где то страница, которую вы как то грузите, на которой якобы есть какой то элемент и он вроде как видимый, но ваш код не видит этот какой то элемент и вы спрашиваете в чем проблема? Она может быть много в чем, тут так не скажешь. К вашему XPath претензий нет.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт открывает страницу, и сразу ищет элемент. Возможно ошибка в том, что страница еще не успела загрузится для Сelenium.

Можно дождаться загрузки так:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "responseDate")))
```

Или после открытия страницы сделать паузу выполнения программы `time.wait(время)`. Последний вариант "костыльный", но им легче узнать действительно ли в этом проблема.